Distortion when increasing Op Amp Input Resistor
I am working on the schematic below. My goal is to create an automatic gain control circuit which can handle inputs from around 5mV to 50mV and amplify them to be in the neighborhood of 2-3V.

The theory of operation for this AGC is that NJF and R10 create a resistive divider at the non-inverting input of OP07 which has a constant voltage gain of 500 (54ish dB). Depending on the output of OP07 a variable DC voltage will be present at the input of NJF's gate. This variable voltage changes the resistance of the gate. negative voltages lead to very high impedances so that v_in is approximately equal to v_oa_in. As the gate voltage approaches 0v the resistance decreases and a larger voltage drop occurs across R10
This project is mostly for experimentation so a lot of my goals are arbitrary. One of my arbitrary goals was to try to get 20 dB of variable attenuation on the input signal. I did this in two ways...
First I can always increase R10. The detriment of this is that I essentially increase my minimum attenuation, but I also increase the dynamic range of my variable attenuator.
Ex. Lets say the NJFETs resistance varies from 50K to 5K.
If R10 = 10K
min_atten = 50K/(10K+50K) = 5/6 = 0.833 = -1.58dB
max_atten = 5k/(10K+5K) = 1/3 = 0.333 = -9.54 dB
Dynamic Range is approximately 8 dB
If R10 = 50K
min_atten = 50K/(50K+50K) = 1/2 = -3dB
max_atten = 5K/(50K+5K) = -20.82 dB
Dynamic Range is approximately 17 dB
Second, I can increase dynamic range by adjusting R1 and R2 which limit the current through drain Q3 and Q4. Limiting Q3/Q4s collect/emitter current leads to less voltage drop across R13 which leads to a more negative voltage at v_gate_njfet. Per the sweep of gate voltage vs resistance below, if I can get v_gate at my minimum input signal to be near -2V I should have much more dynamic range for my variable resistance. It turned out that for my input voltage ranges R1,R2 = 55K pretty much did exactly that.

Note the figure above was generated using the circuit below. Where I defined the resistance as R = V(v_oa_in)/I(R1)

So at this point I was at a dynamic range of about -17.5 dB with a minimum attenuation of almost 0 dB. I am pretty happy with this but wanted to see if I could adjust R10 further to get a better dynamic range so I adjust from R10=70K to R10 = 100K then 500K. At 500K I notice that my output signal looks terribly distorted see the image below.

My question is what is causing this distortion? I know that non-ideal op-amps will draw some amount of current at their inputs in order for the amplifier to work correctly. I wonder if my input resistance is too high and prevents the op-amp getting the bias current it needs?
For reference with R10 = 70K the signal is below. Still some distortion but not nearly as bad. (I really need to take an FFT to check how bad the distortion is but I haven't done that yet)

Although not the purpose of the question I am open to hearing feedback on my design, I know there are other approaches to AGC which use a variable gain amplifier rather than a variable attenuator followed by a constant gain amplifier.
Thank You
EDIT_1
There appears to be some confusion in what transistors Q3 and Q4 are doing so I am including some additional information here. I'll preface this by saying this is my first time designing something like this so if there are any obvious pitfalls/incorrect statements in the following explanation please correct me.
My AGC circuit design started out in this article. In this design the author uses a BC558 PNP transistor to essentially pull the node left of R13 up towards 0V when the signal v_out is at its gate. Essentially it acts like a half-wave rectifier allowing current to flow when the base of the PNP is -0.7V relative the emitter. What I tried to do was create a full wave rectifier using a PNP and an NPN. The goal being that the NPN would conduct on the positive portion of the sinusoid while the PNP would conduct on the negative portion of the wave. In hindsight I could probably go back to only the PNP transistor but when I initially made the change I was using the circuit in the image below and was having trouble getting the 0.1uF capacitor to stay charged for the entire period of the wave without large swings. I was hoping that by rectifying both positive and negative portions of the wave I could solve that issue.

Since I changed my circuit from the above though I could probably use only one of the PNP/NPN transistors. Per the image below my "full-wave" solution doesn't really create a "full wave" it is skewed more which suggests the PNP transistor conducts more then the NPN. V(n007) is the node to the left of R13


I can't see what Q3 and Q4 achieve, even after I redraw that section in a form easier to appraise:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I still didn't see what it's supposed to do, so I have to rely on a simulation. V1 represents the op-amp's output, and a DC sweep of that source yields the following signal at Y:

It's certainly interesting, producing a nice trough near \$V_X = -1.5V\$, but it doesn't explain your issues yet. I can guess that as your op-amp output swings up and down through -1.5V, some representation of this strange function reaches the JFET gate, so let's see what a sinusoid at X (blue)  might become at Y (orange):

Here's what I think is causing your distortion. This signal is being low-pass filtered by C5, R12 and C4, the cut-off frequency being dominated by R12 and C4, at about about \$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi C_4R_{12}}=10Hz\$. Even so, some fraction of potential changes at Y are still going to appear at J2's gate. Another simulation with C5, R12 and C4 in place, and with a 3V peak 200Hz sinusoid at X:

simulate this circuit

You have a signal at J2's gate of 90mV peak to peak. At a guess I would say that's easily enough to modulate the JFET's effective resistance by many kilohms, producing many hundreds of millivolts of change in drain potential. This is applied directly to the op-amp's non-inverting input, as feedback, but looking at the plot above it's clear that there it is very non-linear feedback with strong components at higher harmonics. I can't see how this circuit can fail to distort.
I am guessing that you wish to produce some kind of peak as the output signal crosses -1.5V or so, to signify the need to attenuate, which Q3 and Q4 do quite nicely, but I don't see how this "detector" is supposed to interface with the JFET. I don't see an obvious fix. It looks like you are trying to implement a peak detector with Q3 and Q4, but you've failed to control its "decay", and are instead injecting strong unintended components of multiple harmonics directly into the signal path.
You'll need to arrange to have negligible AC components appearing at J2's gate, nothing with a period shorter than the AGC's intended time constant, so perhaps start by increasing R12 a lot.

+1. Nice penetrating analysis. Following your work, it seems to me that the scope of Q3 and Q4 is to realise an envelope detector in order to control the JFET conductance by a signal that is proportional to the local (in time)maximum envelope of the circuits. What seems strange to me is that the gate control circuits of this kind of devices  try to approximate the RMS value, in order to produce an oscillation with low distortion, while here it is not so.

@DanieleTampieri, what I was going for is an envelope detector yet. I am in the process of editing the original post to explain what the goal of those NPN/PNP transistors is. This entire design is based on an article which I will link in the edit that used a similar technique. I am open to suggestions for my envelope detector, this is really my first time designing something like this, so always looking to learn something new

I would say that, at the non-inverting input, a passive adder consisting of R10 and the DS resistor of the jfet is connected, which, considering also the operational amplifier, is configured as a non-inverting active adder with two inputs.
